# How to read appsettings.json file configuration in Angular 10

Tags: json, angular, typescript, appsettings

I am developing a web application in Angular 10, wanted to access the **appsettings.json** file configurations in the Angular Home component.

This is the appsetting.json file configuration which I need to read.

```
 "Application": {
    "ServiceUrl": "http://localhost:6000/",
    "LogServiceURL": "http://localhost:6002/"
  }
```

Please help me to find out the best solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the npm **read-appsettings-json** package.

install read-appsettings-json through npm package using the following command:

```
`npm install read-appsettings-json --save`
```

Import the "read-appsettings-json" whereever you want to read the appsetting.json file. In your case in home component.

```
import { AppConfiguration } from "read-appsettings-json";
```

Then just write below code to get value from appsetting.json file

```
let serviceURL=AppConfiguration.Setting().Application.ServiceUrl;

let logServiceURL=AppConfiguration.Setting().Application.LogServiceURL;
```

You can refer npm [website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-appsettings-json).

Answer (score 0):

```
import appSettings from '../path_to_json';
```

You can import any JSON or js file like this in Angular/Typescript. You can also get a package.json file as well like this.

you can also create an observable of file like this. but i think its not needed and over-complicated as all this is static data

```
this.http.get('/path/to/appsettings.json').subscribe(result => {
       this.data = result;
    });
```